# ASP.Net core 3.1 website not redirecting when unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.Net core 3.1 application with Identity and 2 pages: Index and Private (authorization required).
When I browse to the Private page directly, I would expect the application to redirect me to the login page.
Yet instead the broswer shows {"message":"Unauthorized"}.
Where is that message coming from and why is it not redirecting to login?

(Navigating to login /Identity/Account/Login directly DOES show the login page)

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<BackendUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
        app.UseStatusCodePages();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Private()
    {
        return View();
    }
   
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `app.UseStatusCodePages`?

Comment: The same without app.UseStatusCodePages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your problem. You might have another problem with your project. You are using some middleware for example.

Anyway, try to logout and login again or **clear the browser cookies**, because the login process adds cookies to the browser to identify authentication. This will renew any broken cookies and probably will fix the authorization problem.

Comment: My bad. The [Authorize] attribute was referring to a custom attribute that caused this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Mine works well however, mine does not have interpolation symbol.

```
options.LoginPath =  "/Identity/Account/Login";
options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
```

Answer (score 0):

This saved me. I removed the $ dollar sign.

Before $"/Identity/Account/Login"
after "/Identity/Account/Login"